# how to draw a filled sector of an ellipse with SDL 2 and C++

Tags: c++, graphics, sdl, ellipse, sector

I have a simple assignment.
I just have to draw some graphics primitives.
The issue is that the assignment was supposed to be done in Turbo C with graphics.h
There is a function called `sector` which is capable of drawing a sector of an ellipse.
I decided to write the assignment with SDL.
I managed to draw all the graphic primitives except for the sector of an ellipse.
I used `gfxPrimitives` library. But the library cannot do this.
Neither SDL_Draw can.

I need to draw something like this
http://www.softwareandfinance.com/Turbo_C/Graphics/sector.html
(The part on the screenshot called "sector 0-270 deg")

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done it.
There is a library called `SDL_bgi`
http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/

It consists of one `.c` file and two headers. I just added the files to the project.
After some adjustments to my code I am able to call `graphics.h` functions from `SDL` project.

Comment: that library is X11 specific.